# Rails load Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Just want to ask questions. I'm having this kind of error whenever I have a rails command. Even the 'rails -v'. This is the error message:

```
/home/jump007/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rails:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /home/jump007/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rails-4.2.1/bin/rails (LoadError)
    from /home/jump007/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
```

I also getting this error when I try to create a new rails project.

this is my rails file:

```
#!/home/jump007/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby
#
# This file was generated by RubyGems.
#
# The application 'rails' is installed as part of a gem, and
# this file is here to facilitate running it.
#

require 'rubygems'

version = ">= 0"

if ARGV.first
  str = ARGV.first
  str = str.dup.force_encoding("BINARY") if str.respond_to? :force_encoding
  if str =~ /\A_(.*)_\z/ and Gem::Version.correct?($1) then
    version = $1
    ARGV.shift
  end
end

gem 'rails', version
load Gem.bin_path('rails', 'rails', version)
```

I used RVM and it works fine. I only use ruby 2.2.1 version. The error started when I installed new gem called rspec and everything goes rough. Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own question. I just uninstalled the rails and re installed it using RVM. I guess the cause of my problem was I installed two versions of rails. Thanks to my instinct ;)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the following command?

```
gem install rails
```

Comment: May you post the result of
`which rails`

and your path variables?

Comment: this is the result of which rails

"/home/jump007/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rails"

Comment: um..
I suspect it is some path settings involving gemdir
Have your ever successfully execute a gem in command line?

Maybe you can check `rvm gemdir`  to see if it match the path.

Comment: I got this result on rvm gemdir

"/home/jump007/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1"